# Randomly Dividing and Storing a SQL Table by Percentage

Tags: python, sql, stored-procedures, ssms

I am trying to split a database in Microsoft's SSMS (SQL Server) for the purpose of using the data in a Machine Learning application.

I would like to separate the data into training and testing tables, at an 80/20 split. Unfortunately, the only way I know of doing this would be taking the top 20% of the table for the test set and then setting the rest of the data as the training set (SELECT TOP 20 percent FROM...).

I do not want to do this, as then my test and training sets are based entirely off of how they are organized in SQL, not on some random seeding.

My end goal would be to have a 80/20 train/test split that I could use in Python Stored Procedures in the SQL Server.

Comment: Do what you described with `ORDER BY NEWID()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate a random distribution, you can `order by newid()`:

```
select top 20 percent * from mytable order by newid()
```

You might also want to have a look at the `tablesample` clause, available since SQL Server 2015. It has an option called `repeatable` that lets the query return the same random recordset everytime your run it (as long the given seed remains the same and as the table is not modified). This could be handy for your use case:

```
select top 20 percent * from mytable order by tablesample(20 percent) repeatable(10)
```

Comment: So the tablesample function works great, thank you for that! Unfortunately though, it doesn't appear that the repeatable function is working. I'm checking my category counts and it seems that each time I run my query (even though I'm using the same seed) I'm getting different results...

Comment: Are you running this query within the same sql-server session, or in different sessions?

Comment: Same session. I was actually testing running the query back-to-back, for the sole purpose of testing uniformity between runs.